# how to display a list based on a foreign key groovy grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have two tables: `Region` and `District`. So `region_id` is the `foreign key` into the table `District` (a `region` has one or many `districts`). So, when I select a `region` on my `list` I only want to display the `districts` associated with that particular `region`.
My correct code displays all the `districts` independently of `region`:

```
def list = {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max? params.int('max') : 20, 100)
        [districtInstanceList : District.list(params),
        districtInstanceTotal: District.count()]
    }
```

Does someone know how to only display based on the foreign key constraint? I know I could write a `SQL` query in my `list` closure, but I suppose grails probably has a way to do it.
My database is `MySQL`, and the `grails` version is `2.0.1`.
My `District` domain is:

```
class District {

def scaffold = true

String name
String description
String logo
String homepage
// defines the 1:n constrain with the Region table
static belongsTo = [region : Region]
// defines the 1: constraint with the Stream table
static hasMany = [streams : Stream]

static constraints ={
    name(blank:false, minSize:6, maxSize:30)
    description(blank: false, maxSize:100)
}

public String toString(){
    name
}
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GORM:

```
def list = {
    params.max = Math.min(params.max? params.int('max') : 20, 100)
    Region region = Region.get(params.id) // or what parameter you're using
    List districts = District.findAllByRegion(region)
    [districtInstanceList : districts,
    districtInstanceTotal: District.count()]
}
```

You can read about Grails GORM here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html

Comment: And I'm getting:
`Error 500: Executing action [list] of controller [ctv.DistrictController] caused exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ctv.District.findAllByRegion() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: findAllByRegion(java.util.List)
Servlet: grails`

Comment: Any idea how can I solve this? `region_id` is just a foreign key in `District`

Comment: Also, thanks for the first thought. I included my domain for `District`

Comment: please check that passed region ins't null

Comment: Igor, You were right. Region is null. Also, could you please give me an idea how do I pass the `id` of the region to the `params`?

Comment: That's the only thing missing, to figure how to pass the `Region` `id` to the `District`

Comment: like `/yourController/list?id=1` or use UrlMapping: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings

Comment: Man, you're da bomb!
Thanks so much!